# Include WCS coordinates in a FITS image

Tags: python, physics, astronomy, astropy

I have a 2D numpy array 'ZEA_N_sky' initially created as

```
n=128
ZEA_N_sky=np.zeros((n,n))
```

and later some values were assigned to every pixel of this array. I can plot this array as FITS image (that can be opened by ds9) using the following code, however I wish to see the WCS coordinates as well. That is, when I roll my mouse cursor over the image, I should be able to see the gal-long, gal-lat;  Right-Asc, Dec , etc. How can I achieve that ? Do i need to do it manually or there is some header() trick ?

The documentation given using WCS package and use all_pix2world() does not seem to work (rather I dont seem to understand it). If somebody can help me please with the code? Thanks !

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np
from astropy import wcs
from astropy.table import Table

out_file_name = 'FITS_image.fits'

hdr = fits.Header()
hdr['Projection'] = "ZEA"
hdr['nd_size'] = str(nd_size)
hdr['SCALE']="nd_size/2"
fits.writeto(out_file_name, ZEA_N_sky, hdr,clobber=True)
```

---

I have made some progress. This is the bit of code I am using right now using which I do obtain the WCS parameters, but the value of longitude that I am getting on my FITS image is wrong ! I think I am making mistake in the ZEA projection parameters values.

```
NSGP=1 #Parameter for North side projection, -1 for south side

w = wcs.WCS(naxis=2)
w.wcs.crpix = [SCALE,SCALE] # SCALE is half the value of my pixel range in the image. n/2=128/2=64
w.wcs.cdelt = np.array([-NSGP*90.0/float(SCALE) * 0.90032, NSGP*90.0/float(SCALE) * 0.90032]) # increments in degrees per pixel
w.wcs.crval = [NSGP*90.0, NSGP*90.0] #RA and dec values in hours and degrees    
w.wcs.ctype = ["GLON-ZEA", "GLAT-ZEA"]
#w.wcs.set_pv([(180, NSGP, float(SCALE))])

out_file_name = 'N_Mateu_ZEA_stream_mask.fits'
# Now, write out the WCS object as a FITS header
header = w.to_header()
hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(ZEA_N_sky,header=header)
hdu.writeto(out_file_name, clobber=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making a WCS object with the correct WCS parameters for your image, and then call `header = wcs.to_header`, and store the image data and header in the FITS file. 
See example [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/wcs/index.html#building-a-wcs-structure-programmatically).

Usually you don't create WCS or headers yourself, it's something you read from FITS files. In that case you do `wcs = WCS(header)` to create a WCS object from the FITS header.
See example [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/wcs/index.html#loading-wcs-information-from-a-fits-file).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have been to that webpage you suggested. I am not very sure how to employ that example in my code. If its not too much of pain, could you really find a worked out solution for me ? I am strongly under impression that it has to be a one or a two liner code.

Comment: That page has a worked solution. I think what you are missing is to know all the ZEA projection parameters and what their names are in the FITS header, no?

Comment: I have made an update to my program that I could not put here. The changes I have made has been added in my question. Please have a look at it. Thanks !

Comment: From the information you have given, we have no way to know what the ZEA projection parameters should be for your image. Can you talk to someone locally that took this image and knows FITS / WCS to help you figure this out?